# 3rd party (stripe) metadata best practices?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, distributed

Is there a best practice of storing metadata in 3rd party systems?

When we create a payment we use stripe metadata to reference a record in our system.

```
StripePaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 200,
  'metadata' => [
    'our_app' => '{'invoice_id': 'invoice_123'}'
  ]
]);
```

Because we use stripe connect this will be visible and editable in the user's platform as seen in the following image.

[image]

I feel like this is too open.

The only other way I could think to do this was base64 encoding which would give us something like:

```
StripePaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 200,
  'metadata' => [
    'our_app' => 'eydpbnZvaWNlX2lkJzogJ2ludm9pY2VfMTIzJ30='
  ]
]);
```

[image]

Is there a best / better way to do this?

Comment: Metadata in Stripe objects is only visible to you (or anyone with access to your secret key, which should be kept secret). It is not visible to your customers,

Comment: @taintedzodiac because we use stripe connect this metadata will be visible to the user

Comment: Ah I see, you mean the connected accounts as your users? In that case, yes, you'd want to likely store the metadata either on your own platform account's object or (more simply) store the metadata in your own system and store a reference id (your own id) that you can use to retrieve the metadata locally.

Comment: Yes the users connected account. I want to store the metadata in the connected users stripe account so I can determine if a payment was created by us or in case of a network error I can pick up back were I left off. The only issue is this metadata is editable and visible to the user. Not really a problem but I just wondered if there was any practical solution / smart way to storing this metadata that I cannot see.